# DropDown menu doesn't select options

Tags: php, sql, drop-down-menu, pfbc

here is the code to get the projects.But somehow it doesn't work.When I click on 'option2' option,it gets back to 'option1'.

```
include("pfbc3.1-php5.3/PFBC/Form.php");
include("pfbc3.1-php5.3/header.php");


if (isset($_POST['project'])) {
    $project = $_POST['project'];
} else {
    $project = 0;
}
if (isset($_POST['new_project'])) {
    $new_project = $_POST['new_project'];
} else {
    $new_project = "";
}
if (isset($_POST['edit'])) {
    $edit = $_POST['edit'];
} else {
    $edit = 0;
}
if (isset($_POST['submit_reset']) && $_POST['submit_reset'] == "Reset") {
    $project = 0;
    $projects = get_projects();
    $options = [];
    $options[0] = "please select";
    foreach ($projects as $project) {
        $options[$project[0]] = $project[1];
    }

    $form = new Form("project-form");
    $form->configure([
        "prevent" => ["bootstrap", "jQuery"],
        "action"  => "right.php?target=management/project"
    ]);
    $form->addElement(new Element\HTML('<legend>Projects</legend>'));
    $form->addElement(new Element\Select("Existing projects:", "project", $options,
        ["onchange" => "this.form.submit()", "value" => $project]));
    $form->addElement(new Element\Textbox("New Project:", "New_Project",
        ["placeholder" => "new project", "shortDesc" => "Add new project", "value" => get_project($project)]));

    $form->addElement(new Element\Button);
```

get_projects function it has the following code :

```
function get_projects(){
    global $db;
    $sql="SELECT ID, project, description FROM [Typematrix].[dbo].[Project] ";
    $arr = $db->GetArray($sql);
    //print_r($arr);
    return $arr;
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Please explain further

Comment: What happens: If I select ,for example: Project one,which is option1,it goes back to please select,which is option 0.And it refreshes itself.

Comment: @M.Marculescu pls edit that into the question for it to be easier to read.

Comment: I edited. Should I put the entire php file?

Comment: Are you using concrete5?

Comment: To write the code? No,I am using Notepad++.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you fill `$project`:

```
if (isset($_POST['project'])) {
    $project = $_POST['project'];
} else {
    $project = 0;
}
```

But later in the code you do:

```
foreach ($projects as $project) {
    $options[$project[0]] = $project[1];
}
```

This overwrites your `$project` value in the loop.

If you rename the value in  the `foreach()` it shouldn't overwrite anymore.

For example:

```
foreach ($projects as $p) {
    $options[$p[0]] = $p[1];
}
```